# JavaScript Total Price List Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

Within my set of price lists, I have radio buttons to select one option. That option then gets added to the total. I then want to have a number of checkboxes that you can select additional multiple options. However, the script only returns £NaN instead of the actual figure. As far as I am aware, I have assigned prices under the array correctly.

I'm stumped and can't find out why it isn't calculating.

As requested, I've included the code in one element. (full code is on codepen: https://codepen.io/Amnesia180/pen/RwKQOKP)

```js
 var burger_prices = new Array();
 burger_prices["1x3oz"]=2;
 burger_prices["2x3oz"]=3;
 
 
function getBurgerSizePrice()
{  
    var burgerSizePrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["custom-burger"];
    var selectedBurger = theForm.elements["burger-meat"];
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBurger.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBurger[i].checked)
        {
            
            burgerSizePrice = burger_prices[selectedBurger[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
   return burgerSizePrice;
}

var burger_Sauces = new Array();
burger_Sauces["burgersauce"]=2;
burger_Sauces["spicyketchup"]=2;

function getBurgerSaucesPrice() {
  var BurgerSaucesPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["custom-burger"];
  var selectedSauces = theForm.elements["selectedSauces"];

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedSauces.length; i++) {
    if(selectedSauces[i].checked){
        BurgerSaucesPrice += burger_Sauces[selectedSauces[i].value];
      break;
    }
  }

  return BurgerSaucesPrice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var burgerPrice = getBurgerSizePrice() + getBurgerSaucesPrice();
    
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Burger £"+burgerPrice;

}
```

```html
  <section class="burgerform">
  <form action="" id="custom-burger" onsubmit="return false;">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Create your Burger Box!</legend>
    <label>Meat</label><p/>
    <input type="radio"  name="burger-meat" value="1x3oz"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    1 x 3oz Beef Patty (£2)<br/>
    <input type="radio"  name="burger-meat" value="2x3oz"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    2 x 3oz Beef Patties (£3)<br/>
     <p/>
   <label>Sauces</label><br/>
    <div class="sauces">
      Burger <input type="checkbox" id="burgersauce" name="selectedSauces" onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
    Dirty Mayo
    <input type="checkbox" id="dirtymayo" name="selectedSauces"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
   Spicy Ketchup
    <input type="checkbox" id="spicyketchup" name="selectedSauces"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
            
   </div>  
     <p>
    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
     </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</section>
</section>
```

Comment: try using `let` instead on `var` inside functions `getBurgerSaucesPrice`.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] i.e one snippt that has the form, multiple elements etc

Comment: Thanks, but it still returns NaN when selecting.

Comment: The first thing that caught my attention was that you're trying to use `Array` as a `Dictionary` ? You can use plain object or `Map` instead for that. Also add all the functions and HTML to your code. For instance, `getBurgerSizePrice` isn't defined and more `form` elements I think. And please add them in **one** snippet. Not separated like you have done for now.

Comment: I had just reduced all the code to try and produce a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Your minimal example should be fully working in itself (working in the essence that the error is reproducible). If there is a function you can omit or if there is an HTML element you don't need, but are still using for **minimal example**, remove it so your original problem could be the focus.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone - apologies if I am making this a little difficult - I'm new and learning. I have now put everything into one snippet as above. I've removed everything that isn't needed and left two examples for each element above. I hope that helps

Comment: Here is the pen on codepen if that helps; https://codepen.io/Amnesia180/pen/RwKQOKP

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `value` on `input` elements but that doesn't exist as it's attribute in your **HTML**. You can just use the `id` attribute instead since those map with the **keys** in `burger_Sauces` object.

**Note**: you were seeing `NaN` because `.value` was returning `undefined` and a **number** operation on `undefined` results in `NaN`. Also you might want to calculate **burger sauces price** only when a **burger patty** is selected. I haven't added that check but just a heads up.

```js
var burger_prices = {};
 burger_prices["1x3oz"]=2;
 burger_prices["2x3oz"]=3;
 
 
function getBurgerSizePrice()
{  
    var burgerSizePrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["custom-burger"];
    var selectedBurger = theForm.elements["burger-meat"];
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBurger.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBurger[i].checked)
        {
            
            burgerSizePrice = burger_prices[selectedBurger[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
   return burgerSizePrice;
}

var burger_Sauces = {}
burger_Sauces["burgersauce"]=2;
burger_Sauces["dirtymayo"]=2;
burger_Sauces["spicyketchup"]=2;

function getBurgerSaucesPrice() {
  var BurgerSaucesPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["custom-burger"];
  var selectedSauces = theForm.elements["selectedSauces"];

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedSauces.length; i++) {
    if(selectedSauces[i].checked){
        BurgerSaucesPrice += burger_Sauces[selectedSauces[i].id];
    }
  }

  return BurgerSaucesPrice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var burgerPrice = getBurgerSizePrice() + getBurgerSaucesPrice();
    
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Burger £"+burgerPrice;

}
```

```html
<section class="burgerform">
  <form action="" id="custom-burger" onsubmit="return false;">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Create your Burger Box!</legend>
    <label>Meat</label><p/>
    <input type="radio"  name="burger-meat" value="1x3oz"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    1 x 3oz Beef Patty (£2)<br/>
    <input type="radio"  name="burger-meat" value="2x3oz"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    2 x 3oz Beef Patties (£3)<br/>
     <p/>
   <label>Sauces</label><br/>
    <div class="sauces">
      Burger <input type="checkbox" id="burgersauce" name="selectedSauces" onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
    Dirty Mayo
    <input type="checkbox" id="dirtymayo" name="selectedSauces"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
   Spicy Ketchup
    <input type="checkbox" id="spicyketchup" name="selectedSauces"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
            
   </div>  
     <p>
    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
     </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost worked. Your only problem was this line:

```
BurgerSaucesPrice += burger_Sauces[selectedSauces[i].value];
```

You should have typed it:

```
BurgerSaucesPrice += burger_Sauces[selectedSauces[i].id];  /* use id not value */
```

You also forgot to assign a value for `dirtymayo`, so I decided to choose an arbitrary value for it.

```
burger_Sauces["dirtymayo"]=3;
```

And lastly, you had a `break` in the for loop that calculates the Sauce total. That will cause it to stop counting all other selected sauces after it counts the first selected on. So I had to comment that `break` out.

```
   // break;   // you should continue to check for other sauces
```

My guess is that you copied the logic from the radio button group (which makes sense to exit from for loop once you encountered the first selected option), and then forgot to remove the break from the checkbox group.

```js
 var burger_prices = new Array();
 burger_prices["1x3oz"]=2;
 burger_prices["2x3oz"]=3;
 
 
function getBurgerSizePrice()
{  
    var burgerSizePrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["custom-burger"];
    var selectedBurger = theForm.elements["burger-meat"];
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBurger.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBurger[i].checked)
        {
            
            burgerSizePrice = burger_prices[selectedBurger[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
   return burgerSizePrice;
}

var burger_Sauces = new Array();
burger_Sauces["burgersauce"]=2;
burger_Sauces["spicyketchup"]=2;
burger_Sauces["dirtymayo"]=3;

function getBurgerSaucesPrice() {
  var BurgerSaucesPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["custom-burger"];
  var selectedSauces = theForm.elements["selectedSauces"];

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedSauces.length; i++) {
    if(selectedSauces[i].checked){
        BurgerSaucesPrice += burger_Sauces[selectedSauces[i].id];  /* use id not value */
       // break;   // you should continue to check for other sauces
    }
  }

  return BurgerSaucesPrice;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var burgerPrice = getBurgerSizePrice() + getBurgerSaucesPrice();
    
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Burger £"+burgerPrice;

}
```

```html
  <section class="burgerform">
  <form action="" id="custom-burger" onsubmit="return false;">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Create your Burger Box!</legend>
    <label>Meat</label><p/>
    <input type="radio"  name="burger-meat" value="1x3oz"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    1 x 3oz Beef Patty (£2)<br/>
    <input type="radio"  name="burger-meat" value="2x3oz"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    2 x 3oz Beef Patties (£3)<br/>
     <p/>
   <label>Sauces</label><br/>
    <div class="sauces">
      Burger <input type="checkbox" id="burgersauce" name="selectedSauces" onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
    Dirty Mayo
    <input type="checkbox" id="dirtymayo" name="selectedSauces"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
   Spicy Ketchup
    <input type="checkbox" id="spicyketchup" name="selectedSauces"
    onclick="calculateTotal()" /><br/>
            
   </div>  
     <p>
    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
     </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</section>
</section>
```